# Applet on Website seems to hate Packages

Tags: java, applet, classnotfoundexception

So I made an Applet (not JApplet) and proceeded to upload it to my website. I put all of my .class files into a package, exported the project from eclipse to a .jar, and uploaded that to the public_html folder of my website.

In my HTML code, I put

```
<applet ARCHIVE="BallShooter.jar" CODE="BallShooter" width=500 height=500> </applet>
```

However, it seems that I kept on getting the error "ClassNotFoundException"
If I reupload the .jar WITHOUT the package, it worked fine. Could somebody please explain to me how to fix this?

For those who are wondering, this is the structure of the things in the website

```
/public_html/myAppletJar/myPackage/a.class  
/public_html/myAppletJar/myPackage/b.class  
/public_html/myAppletJar/a.png  
/public_html/myAppletJar/b.png
```

Comment: Can  you show us the folder structure for both?

Comment: sure i'll update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check all these points:

- if the applet class is `BallShooter`, and is in the package `kikiotsuka`, then its source code must start with the line `package kikiotsuka;`. The full name of the class is thus `kikiotsuka.BallShooter`.
- in the jar file, you should thus have a directory named `kikiotsuka` at the root, and this directory must contain a file named `BallShooter.class`
- since the name of the class is `kikiotsuka.BallShooter`, that's what the code attribute of the applet HTML element must contain: `code="kikiotsuka.BallShooter" width=...`

Comment: I think you mean "applet class" in the first bullet, instead of "servlet class".